# In Splunk how to find the number of words based on the a pipe separator and add a value to it and assign it to a new filed

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-formula

Hi Have an event like this shown below

**Today's Greeting Messag=Hello|myname|name|is|Alice|myName|is|bob"}**

How can i count the number of words between **message=** till **"}**. I have a **|** delimiter that should helps me to get the count of words in between. But for every count i want to add a specific number

example for above log i will get 8 words in between as count based on **|** separator.
But for every count i would like to add some new number like 8+2 and the value to be updated to a new splunk field.

This will help in calculating if any event that is crossing the threshold of that value then i can trigger an alarm.

Some one please help me in getting this.

Comment: For identifying the string following regex i have used Messag=.*\"}|

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, which splits the string in to a multi value field of each word, then counts the number of values in that field. You can then add whatever numbers to the end as you need.

```
| eval msg_mv=split(msg,"|")
| eval words = mvcount(msg_mv)-1
| eval final_count = words+2
```

Comment: why make it so complicated? Just do `eval count=mvcount(split(msg,"|"))`. No need to subtract 1

Comment: I prefer to split up a search line by line so it's clearer what everything does, and this the original poster will learn how to build similar queries inn the future

Comment: Yes..But I am very new to splunk.